# C++/SFML program crashes on exit

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, crash, sfml

I just recently started playing around with SFML and I wrote this simple program.

I'm using visual studio 2010 btw.

The program compiles and runs fine when using the "start debugging" option.
but if I open the .exe file as if I was running a normal desktop application or something, it will crash on exit.

I've spent a while trying to figure it out but all I can say is that it's probably a heap corruption.

here's all the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


void moveSquare();
void avgFPS();

class displayFPS : public sf::Thread{
public:
private:
    virtual void Run();
};

int checkEvent(sf::RenderWindow &win){
    sf::Event Event;
    while(win.GetEvent(Event)){
        // Window closed
        if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed){
            return 0;
        }
        // Escape key pressed
        if ((Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape)){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32),"Mario Clone Test");
sf::Image img1(200,200,sf::Color(255,255,0));
sf::Sprite sprite1;
std::stringstream ss;
sf::String fps;
bool threadFPS;

int main(){
    sprite1.SetImage(img1);
    sprite1.SetCenter(-300,-300);
    win.SetFramerateLimit(30);
    moveSquare();
    win.Close();
    sf::Sleep(0.5);
    return 0;
}

void moveSquare(){
    displayFPS dispFPS;
    threadFPS = true;
    dispFPS.Launch();
    fps.SetSize(20);
    while(1){
        if(!win.IsOpened() || checkEvent(win) == 0){
            threadFPS = false;
            dispFPS.Wait();
            break;
        }
        win.Draw(sprite1);
        win.Draw(fps);
        win.Display();
        win.Clear();
        if(win.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Left)){
            sprite1.Move(-100*win.GetFrameTime(),0);
        }
        if(win.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Right)){
            sprite1.Move(100*win.GetFrameTime(),0);
        }
        if(win.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Up)){
            sprite1.Move(0,-100*win.GetFrameTime());
        }
        if(win.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Down)){
            sprite1.Move(0,100*win.GetFrameTime());
        }
    }
    return;
}

void avgFPS(){
    double frames=0.0,avg=0.0;
    int j=0;
    while(threadFPS){
        if(win.GetFrameTime() != 0){
            j++;
            frames = frames+(1.0/win.GetFrameTime());
            avg = frames/j;
        }
        ss << "avg FPS: " << avg << std::endl << "Arrow Keys to Move" << std::endl << "Press ESC to Exit";
        fps.SetText(ss.str());
        ss.str("");
    }
    return;
}

void displayFPS::Run(){
    avgFPS();
}
```

Comment: First thing's first: are you **absolutely sure** that the .exe you are running outside the debugger resulted from compiling **this** code? It could be an executable from a previous version of the code. Note that if you are compiling in one mode (Debug or Release) the other mode will not be built (so it could be that you've been compiling a debug version and you in the past compiled a Release one and you're running it and it's crashing). Delete the .exe, recompile, and see if it reappears again.

Comment: I just deleted the .exe right now and build it again. Yea, it still crashes on exit. I do have 1 warning when building: "LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library".  as well as "First-chance exception at 0x7781e3be in Mario Clone.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xdbcf7c05." when debugging.

Comment: Step through the code, setting breakpoints where appropriate, and see where the exception occurs; the debugger is preventing it from crashing.

Comment: As I step through, the exception occurs after "return 0;". I start stepping through some file called "crtexe.c" then on "exit(mainret);" the exception occurs and the debugging ends and the debug log says "The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1f94) has exited with code 0 (0x0)", "The program '[4116] Mario Clone.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." which I assume means program has ended normally.

Comment: You have a lot of `return 0;`s so I don't know where that is

Comment: the "return 0;" of the "main()". sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think it's something in the destructor of one of your global variables. Try putting them as local variables in `main` inside `{ }` to limit their scope. If you need to access them from other functions, make global pointers and make them point to the local objects in `main`. If the exception occurs when exiting the `}`, then it's one of the destructors of those objects and you can narrow it down by moving them one by one out of the `{ }`.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, it was one of the global variables.  it was "sf::string fps;", can you explain why it causes problems?

Comment: What version of sfml are you using?

Comment: `sf::String` doesn't have a destructor, so it's the destructor of one of the objects it contains, which are: a `Unicode::Text`, a `ResourcePtr<Font>`, and a `FloatRect`. You'll have to see which of those are causing the segfault (I recommend setting a breakpoint in the destructors of those).

Comment: But first, make VS break on first chance exceptions and try running it again, that may lead you to the error more quickly: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/18/440150.aspx

Comment: ok, i played around some more with sfml and stuff, and I realized it's not sf::string directly causing the problem.......
`int main(){
 sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32),"Test App");
 sf::String hello;
 return 0;
}`
causes the exception, but if i declare it the otherway around, as in declare the sf::string before declaring sf::RenderWindow then everything is ok. Can you explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue.
You need to recompile SFML when using VS2010.

Comment: It's also strongly advised to use SFML 2, because SFML 1.6 hasn't been maintained for over 2.5 years, has quite a few ugly bugs (i.e. ATI bug) and lacks a lot of nice features (`sf::RenderTexture`, `sf::VertexArray`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Few things for you to try:

1. If you are suspecting heap corruption, run gflags (found in [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=debugging%20tools%20for%20windows&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009&ei=kL8gT_CFI4ei8gOj1LymBw&usg=AFQjCNFQJgYHFtxbqsRFrnquFGbuVM1Nwg)) and enable page heap.  Some instructions on how it works can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543097%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Basically when page heap is enabled, your app will crash at the point of the memory error, not sometime later.
2. You said you get a crash on exit. When that happens, I'm assuming windows throws up a crash dialog box. Open one of those links that say something like "see what information is being uploaded".  Somewhere among those files will be a minidump of your process.  You can load that up in visual studio (open file and hit F5).  Sometimes visual studio is glitchy, so another, more reliable but more difficult but more difficult to use alternative is WinDbg, also part of Debugging Tools for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

SFML has multiple versions of their .lib's for release and debug.

**Examples:**

- sfml-audio.lib
- sfml-audio-d.lib
- sfml-audio-s.lib
- sfml-audio-s-d.lib

Make sure you are using the lib without the -d in it.

Also, when you put the .dll's with your exe (assuming you are using the dynamic libraries) make sure to use the normal versions not the debug (-d) versions.

Finally, when you are building the project make sure you build for release and not debug.